# Uploading an exe file to github pages and allowing it to be used on the site?

Tags: github, github-pages

Basically the title, I want to have a pretty simple exe file uploaded to my github pages website, and then allow it to be used on the site. Is this possible and if so how can i do it?

Comment: Are you asking if you can make your GitHub Pages site run or otherwise invoke the executable, or are you just trying to allow it to be distributed from the GitHub Pages site?

Comment: the first one, im trying to let people use the exe on the site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Pages provides only static sites.  That is, a GitHub Pages site can contain only HTML, CSS, JavaScript and the like that are delivered without changes to the web browser.  Like with all static site hosts, there is no backend server to perform operations on behalf of the user, including running executables of any sort, so that isn't possible here.

This is the case because GitHub does not want to run arbitrary code on behalf of users when rendering pages (which is a sensible approach in terms of security).  Even if GitHub did support that, GitHub uses Linux, so exe files would be right out.

Comment: ah okay, thank you!